# Android Facebook Login in non Activity Class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible to do a Facebook Login in Android in an non-Activity class?

I have an activity which loads different "Setting Classes" for Social Media Logins etc.
One of them is Facebook. This is a non Activity class which loads my Facebook-Settings.xml. There are some Switch Buttons etc. Save switch button status is working.
I have also integrated the Facebook Login Button. But it seems the onSuccess is not called

What am I missing or doing wrong here? Is it even possible to login to Facebook in a non-activity class?

```
public class FacebookService extends SensorService {

public FacebookService() {
    super("fb");
}

//add Sensorname UI
@Override
public void load() {

    name.setText("FACEBOOOK");
}

//load settings xml-file if settings button is clicked
@Override
public int getSettingsViewId() {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }

    return R.layout.fb_settings;

}


//Saves Checked Buttons from Facebook Seetings
@Override
public void save(View settings) {

    TextView text = (TextView) settings.findViewById(R.id.FBText);
    switchPosts = (Switch) settings.findViewById(R.id.switchPosts);

    }



//Creates View for Facebook Settings
//loads Check Buttons state from Shared preferences and updates view
@Override
public void createSettings(View settings) {

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) settings.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile, email, user_about_me, user_posts, user_friends, user_events, user_photos, user_likes, user_relationships, user_birthday");
    getLoginDetails(loginButton);
}


protected void getLoginDetails(LoginButton login_button){

    // Callback registration
    login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
            Log.d("app", "FB Login");

            accessToken = login_result.getAccessToken();
            if(accessToken != null){
                //statusFacebook.setText("Login Erfolgreich");
                Log.d("app", "Login success");
            }
            else{
                //statusFacebook.setText("Login fehlgeschlagen");
                Log.d("app", "Login no success");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // code for cancellation
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //  code to handle error
        }
    });
}



private void setSwitches() {

  //DO Something
}
 }
```

I start the FacebookService.class from my Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     ....
    ServiceManager.getInstance().setContext(this);
    ServiceManager.getInstance().setRoot((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.service_view));

    ServiceManager.getInstance().add(new FacebookService());
    ServiceManager.getInstance().add(new TwitterService());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You receive the result of login into `onActivityResult` method of your `Activity` or `Fragment`. Then into that method you must pass the result to the `CallbackManager`. This step is not automatic.

So you need something like this (this the `Fragment`'s method)

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

If you want to implement login in non `Activity` class you must anyway add at least this code

Comment: OK thanks. Im really new to Android programming. What or where do you mean do I have to implement at least this code? I want to implement the login in non Activity Class. I need to implement onActivityResult() in my Activity and pass it to the non activity class?

Comment: Exactly. Or in a Fragment if you FacebookService is referenced in it. Keep in mind that onActivityResult is available in Activity and Fragment class but differs a little

Comment: No. I didn't work. my FacebookService is not an Activity or an Fragment Class. It is just a "normal" Java Class. I have an Activity Class where I add my settings Button for the FacebookService. Clicking on this Button loads the FacebookService View which is not an Activity. In this I wanted to add the facebook Login

Comment: In Android you must act into an Activity context, right? Or in a Fragment context. All your others classes act into one of these two contexts. So you must start from there to implement onActivityResult. What tutorial are you reading to achieve your goal?

Comment: This wasn't a tutorial, actually I was trying around to achieve what I wanted. What I have now is working except the Facebook Login in my nonActivity FacebookService.class. I have updated my Question with the code where I start the FacebookService.class.

Comment: I think you can't achieve your goal with this approach. It is not explicitated into facebook docs, but reading what they say I think LoginButton start an Activity to manage login process. And if it is right, Android default behaviour to make inter activities communication is with onActivityResult. Why do you want to realize this non Activity approach?

Comment: Because in this app it should be possible to integrate more then one Social Media, like Facebook and Twitter. So I have in my Main Activity a FacebookSettings Button and an Twitter Settings Button, clicking FBSettingButton  it should be possible to login to Facebook and/or clicking on TwitterSettingButton it should be possible to login to Twitter.

Comment: This is not the approach suggested by official doc. What you need IMHO is to add all of your buttons into a single Activity (eg. SocialMediaActivity) exclusively dedicated to init social media functions. In this way you could also make a social media module to reuse. Better approach is with fragments that garantue maximum flexiblity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation about it, but technically it is possible. Here is how I achieved this:

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.saddan.facebook_login_mvc;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

LoginButton loginButton;

private FacebookLogin Login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton=findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    Login=new FacebookLogin(loginButton,this);
    Login.facebookLogin();
    Login.checkLoginStatus();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,@Nullable Intent data) {
    Login.onActivityResultFB(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

And my Facebook Login Class is:

```
package com.saddan.facebook_login_mvc;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;



public class FacebookLogin
{
   private LoginButton loginButton;
   private Context context;
   private CallbackManager callbackManager;



public FacebookLogin(LoginButton loginButton, Context context)
{
    this.loginButton = loginButton;
    this.context = context;
}

public void facebookLogin()
{

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile","user_friends"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new  FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "error log", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });

}

public void onActivityResultFB(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data) ;

}

AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken)
    {
        if(currentAccessToken==null)
        {

            Toast.makeText(context,"User Logged out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
            loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken);
    }
};

private void loadUserProfile(AccessToken newAccessToken)
{
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
        {
            try {

                String first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                String email = object.getString("email");
                String id = object.getString("id");
                String image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+ "/picture?type=normal";

                Log.d("Name", first_name+" "+last_name);
                Log.d("email", email);
                Log.d("image", image_url);


            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Error_fb","fb"+e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","first_name,last_name,email,id");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}

public void checkLoginStatus()
{

    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
    {
        loadUserProfile(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
    }
 }
}
```

One thing you really need to concentrate is `onActivityResult` method, which you can't use to any normal class,see my `MainActivity` and my Facebook login class how I override `onActivityResult` for facebook login.

If you are useing Fragment instead of Activity you can initialize like this

```
loginButton.setFragment(this);
Login=new FacebookLogin(loginButton,getActivity());
```