# Facebook login From multiple activities in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app in which user can do facebook login from different activity, i already implemented facebook login for one activity using facebook sdk docs but don't know how to implements for other activities, if possible i want to create a centralized code that will take care of facebook login. please help me  Any suggestion or help would be appreciated

Comment: did you resolved your problem ?

Comment: yes i had solved my problem, i'm using fragment without UI for this, your answer is also correct but i haven't used it..(i appreciate your effort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create some FBHelper class like this

```
public class FBHelper {

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private Context context;
    private final String ACCES_TOKEN = "access_token";
    private final String ACCES_EXPIRES = "access_expires";
    private Facebook facebook;
    private FBHelperCallbacks callback;
    public FBHelper(Context context, Facebook facebook)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }
    public void setSignInFinishListener(FBHelperCallbacks callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void FacebookSingleSignIn() {
        mPrefs = ((Activity)context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString(ACCES_TOKEN, null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong(ACCES_EXPIRES, 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Log.i("Facebook","Facebook session is not valid based on acces token... authorizing again");
            facebook.authorize((Activity)context, new String[] {"user_about_me"},new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    callback.onError(e.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.i("Facebook","onError inner");
                    callback.onError(e.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString(ACCES_TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
                    Log.i("Facebook","Saving acces token:"+facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong(ACCES_EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    callback.onSignedInFinished(facebook.getAccessToken());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    callback.onError("onCancel");
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Facebook","Accces token read form preferencesno no need to authorize");
            callback.onSignedInFinished(facebook.getAccessToken());
        }

    }
    public String LogOut()
    {
        try {
            //set ACCES_TOKEN to null 
            mPrefs = ((Activity)context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString(ACCES_TOKEN, null);
            editor.putLong(ACCES_EXPIRES, 0);
            editor.commit();
            return facebook.logout(context);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Error";
    }

    public static abstract class FBHelperCallbacks{
        public abstract void onSignedInFinished(String accesToken);
        public abstract void onError(String message);

    }

}
```

This is how you use this class.

```
public class LogInActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "LogInActivity";
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Context context;
    private Facebook facebook;
    private FBHelper fbhelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        this.context = this;

        Handler pauser = new Handler();
        pauser.postDelayed (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            facebook = new Facebook(context.getString(R.string.FACEBOOK_APP_ID));
            fbhelper = new FBHelper(context, facebook);
            if (aHelper.isLogedIn())
            {
                //log out
                fbhelper.LogOut();
            }
            else
            {
                //facebook login
                fbhelper.setSignInFinishListener(fbcallback);
                            fbhelper.FacebookSingleSignIn();

            }
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    FBHelperCallbacks fbcallback = new FBHelperCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onSignedInFinished(String accesToken) {
            Log.d(TAG,"log in finish");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its only possible when you create a separate class for facebook authentication/login,So whenever you want you can call it anywhere from activity or fragment.Is it possible to authenticate facebook login in a non-activity or a simple java class?yes possible!

[check the link where I answered how you can use facebook Authentication/login in a separate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763702/android-facebook-login-in-non-activity-class/58221959#58221959)